# How to install pyqt6 designer?

Tags: python, pyqt6

I have python 3.10 and have had no problem installing pyqt6.  But the designer package will not install.  I know somebody made a windows installer but it does not have the latest version to support qt6.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
(venv) c:\Users\Lawrence\PycharmProjects\learnpyqt6>pip install pyqt6-tools
Collecting pyqt6-tools
  Using cached pyqt6_tools-6.1.0.3.2-py3-none-any.whl (29 kB)
  Using cached pyqt6_tools-6.0.3.3.2-py3-none-any.whl (29 kB)
  Using cached pyqt6_tools-6.0.2.3.2-py3-none-any.whl (29 kB)
Collecting pyqt6==6.0.2
  Using cached PyQt6-6.0.2.tar.gz (940 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [29 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\Lawrence\PycharmProjects\learnpyqt6\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 156, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
          hook = backend.prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
      AttributeError: module 'sipbuild.api' has no attribute 'prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel'

      During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\Lawrence\PycharmProjects\learnpyqt6\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 363, in <module>
          main()
        File "C:\Users\Lawrence\PycharmProjects\learnpyqt6\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 345, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
(snip)
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

Comment: Try `python3 -m pip install PyQt6 --upgrade`, Then install tools if needed.